# How to specify the axis over which to get the elements in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I was looking for an answer around SO, but tbh, don't even know how to phrase a question.

Given a tensor, how do I get indices over a specified axis

#### Here is a simple example

```py
indices = torch.tensor([2, 4, 5])

# Depending on the context I need either
y = x[indices]

# Or
y = x[:, indices]

# Or any other axis
y = x[:, :, :, indices]
```

#### Here is a usecase where I need this behavior

```py
def remove_weaklings(x: Tensor, percentage: float, axis: int) -> Tensor:
    all_axes = set(range(x.ndim)) - set([axis])
    y = x
    # Sumup over all other axes
    for a in all_axes:
        y = y.sum(axis=a, keepdim=True)
    y = y.squeeze()
    # Get the sorted list
    _, idx = torch.sort(y)
    # Get only a fraction of the list
    idx = idx[:int(percentage * len(idx))]
    # Get the indices over some axis
    # !!! This part not sure how to solve !!!
    return x.get_over_axis(axis=axis, indices=idx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`topk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.topk.html?highlight=topk#torch.topk):

```py
def remove_weaklings(x, percentage, axis):
  k = int(percentage * x.shape[axis])
  return torch.topk(x, k, dim=axis)
```

---

If you want a more generic solution, you can use `numpy`'s [slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html):

```py
def get_over_axis(x, indices, axis):
  i = []
  for d_ in range(x.dim()):
    if d_ == axis:
      i.append(indices)
    else:
      i.append(np.s_[:])
  return x[tuple(i)]
```

Comment: Good call on the `topk` -- didn't think about it. As for the generic numpy solution, I cannot use it. The problem is that the input  is a huge embeddings tensor, which means creating a copy of it will be mega-expensive

Comment: @RafazZ you do not create a copy of it. You only create "slicing" elements. The `tuple(i)` is very compact regardless of `x` size.